# Postgresql 9.4 installation/Windows 8.1/ COMSPEC issue

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation, environment-variables

I've just downloaded postgreSQL 9.4 from http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows for windows x86-64. 
And when I Launch the installer i got an error:
`The environment variable COMSPEC does not seem to point to the cmd.exe or there is a trailing semi colon present.`
I checked it with command 
`echo %COMSPEC%`
`C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`
no semi colon.

What I 've already tested:
Everything listed there :[Problems Installing PostgreSQL 9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287207/problems-installing-postgresql-9-2) and all links from this page.

Thx for help,

Info : Windows 8.1 64bits, user: as admin.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem a while ago, but I fixed it. In fact, it's quite easy.
Just open Advanced System Settings in Control Panel and create a new System Variable( mind it 'System Variable' instead of 'User Variable'

In the variable name, enter 'ComSpec' and then in the variable value , enter 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe'.

That's all. Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from the user folder name. It has a special character:`&`.
Changing the name make it work perfectly.
For those who encounter this issue, be advised that changing users folder name is not an easy task, and from my side, I reinstalled Windows and took care of the computer's name.

Answer (score 1):

For me in addition to the above methods, I overcame this issue by following the steps below:

1. Win+R and type `REGEDIT`
2. Browse to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Command Processor`
3. Here right-click on Autorun and click Modify.
4. Under value data change the value to `0`.
5. Solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

## Easy fix:

1. Open Environment Variables, you can do this on Windows 7 by typing "environment variables" in the Search program and files bar when pressing start button at bottom left of desktop. And create a new System Variable( in the 'System Variable' instead of 'User Variable' section).
2. In the variable name, enter 'ComSpec' and then in the variable value , enter 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe'.

That's all. Hope it works!

## Alternative fix:

If you got akready the ComSpec variable in the System Variable section, remove the `;`at the end of it this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but other solutions did not work for me. I also changed the environment variable name and value. Later during exploring, I found that this error comes due to a virus in your system. I installed Rkill antivirus software that helped me to run my cmd and it works for me and I install PostgreSQL smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution %ComSpec%\System32\cmd.exe

%ComSpec%\System32\cmd.exe[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCT4F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a environment variable named COMPSPEC all caps and add this in path C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open the CMD prompt as administrator and enter the command

fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1

Restart the computer.

Worked for me on Windows 10.

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer you should explain what the command does and why it solves the problem. At least a short version of it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem too, and I solved it by changing the 'Value' databox to 1. Here are the detailed steps, hope it will be helpful to you.

1. Window + R => REGEDIT
2. Locate and then click the registry subkey: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem**.
3. Right-click NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation, and then click Modify.
4. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.