# PostgreSQL Installation Error: The environment variable COMSPEC does not seem to point to the cmd.exe

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation

I am new to **PostgreSQL** and when I tried to install **PostgreSQL 13 / 14** on my **Windows 10** device I encountered the following error.

```
"The environment variable COMSPEC does not seem to point to the cmd.exe or there is a training semicolon present. Please fix this variable and restart installation."
```

[The screenshot of the pop up error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBXTF.png)

**COMSPEC System Variable**

This is the setting of my COMSPEC [environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu5tD.png)

**The Content of the**   `installbuilder_installer.log`

```
Log started 05/06/2022 at 17:51:52
Preferred installation mode : qt
Trying to init installer in mode qt
Mode qt successfully initialized
Setting variable whoami from C:\WINDOWS\System32\whoami 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 atrapa\junkwong

Script stderr:
 

Executing C:\WINDOWS\System32\icacls "C:\Users\junkwong\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_c7c2d91f40" /inheritance:r
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 processed file: C:\Users\junkwong\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_c7c2d91f40
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Script stderr:
 

Executing C:\WINDOWS\System32\icacls "C:\Users\junkwong\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_c7c2d91f40" /T /Q /grant "atrapa\junkwong:(OI)(CI)F"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Script stderr:
 

Executing C:\WINDOWS\System32\cscript //NoLogo "C:\Users\junkwong\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_c7c2d91f40\prerun_checks.vbs"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 The scripting host appears to be functional.

Script stderr:
 

Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 Base Directory. Setting variable iBaseDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 Branding. Setting variable iBranding to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 Version. Setting variable brandingVer to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 Shortcuts. Setting variable iShortcut to empty value
[17:52:01] Using branding: PostgreSQL 14
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 SB_Version. Setting variable sb_version to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 pgAdmin_Version. Setting variable pgadmin_version to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 CLT_Version. Setting variable clt_version to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-14 Data Directory. Setting variable server_data_dir to empty value
Executing C:\Users\junkwong\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_c7c2d91f40/temp_check_comspec.bat 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 

Script stderr:
 

Exiting with code 1
```

And the COMSPEC variable is indeed **set as a System Variable not a User Variable** like many posts proposed. Also, there is no trailing semi colon (;)

**What I have tried:**

1. I have ran the `"%COMSPEC%" /C "echo test ok"` on my command prompt and got "test ok" as result [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPYVz.png)
2. Ran the installation on Administrator cmd.
3. To install different versions of PostgreSQL including 14.2.2, 14.3.1 and 13.7.1 (all produce the same error message)
4. Tried out the solution proposed by Prayash Koirala but no `Command Processor` file can be found [Postgresql 9.4 installation/Windows 8.1/ COMSPEC issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174420/postgresql-9-4-installation-windows-8-1-comspec-issue)
5. Tried this [Problems Installing PostgreSQL 9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287207/problems-installing-postgresql-9-2) . but the `bitrock_installer_xxxx.log` is absent from the suggested path

Thank you very much, any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Have a good day.

Regards,
Jun Kang

Comment: Did you contact the maintainer of the Windows installer? Maybe they made a mistake and now how to fix it

Answer (score 9):

1. Run the following command at a command prompt:

   fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1
2. Restart the computer.

This is a solution from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/stop-error-code-0x00000019, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and search all over. Have tried a lot but finally
I found a working solution. Seems like the problem is related to handling
of 8.3 filenames. I followed the tip in: https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/solved-installation-error-on-windows-10-x64-registerservice-bat/td-p/209616

or go directly to

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/121007/how-to-disable-8.3-file-name-creation-on-ntfs-partitions

Compared to the guide my default registry key was 2 and not 0. Anyhow,
changing it to 1 (+reboot) allowed the COMSPEC-test to pass.
Seems to be a "installation script" vs "Win10" issue...

/Björn

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem once again, and [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271531/postgresql-installation-error-the-environment-variable-comspec-does-not-seem-to/72953421#72953421) didn't work for me this time.

I solved the problem by instead of using classic PostgreSQL installer, I set this up with a Docker.

1. Install Docker Desktop

   https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/
2. Start installed Docker Desktop
3. In PowerShell, run:

   docker pull postgres
4. In PowerShell, run:

   docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword postgres
5. Now you can connect to the Postgres server for example with pgAdmin on the same machine, using:

   - host: localhost
   - port: 5432
   - maintenance database: postgres
   - username: postgres
   - password: mypassword

Comment: Thanks, after trying the others, this solved the issue for me. One small addition: after step 4, you have to go into the docker container: `docker exec -it postgres bash`. Then, you execute `psql <connection_string>` from within the docker container

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have faced the same issue but then i changed the environment variables of CompSpec to name: ComSpec and the path: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe and restarted my pc and it installed successfully. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error like yesterday man and the answer above is pretty correct. I am just going to elaborate the procedure in clearor steps.

First, right-click on the Windows icon on your taskbar and select `System`.

In the `Settings` window, under `Related Settings`, click `Advanced system settings`.

On the `Advanced` tab, click `Environment Variables`.

Under `System Variables` click `New` to create a new environment variable. Name it `ComSpec` and set the path to point to `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`

After creating the environment variable click `Apply` and then OK to have the change take effect.

Restart might be required.

Peace.

Answer (score 0):

If the following error is displayed when running the installation.exe

> Environment variables COMSPEC does not seem to point to The cmd.exe or
> there is a trailing semicolon present.

Most likely, the problem is with the antivirus and the command line is also blocked.

**To solve this problem, follow the instructions below:**

1. Uninstall or disable the antivirus
2. To restore CMD, enter the `.\sfc /scannow` command in the PowerShell as
   administer

Now that everything is back to normal, you can successfully run the installation.exe file. Note that your antivirus does not prevent the installation of postgresql again.