# When I double-click the postgresql installed, can't run, and display the error

Tags: postgresql, installation

I've been trying to install the 64bit version of PostgreSQL 9.2 for windows on my machine (Windows 7 64bit) and i get an error The environment variable COMPSPEC does not seem to point to the cmd.exe or there is a trailing semicolon present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems Installing PostgreSQL 9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287207/problems-installing-postgresql-9-2) -- same exact error message for same version of postgres

Answer (score 0):

Your environment variables have been modified incorrectly by some other program or installer. You need to fix it, setting the system environment variable `COMSPEC` to `"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe"` and deleting any user environment variable ntry for `COMSPEC` that might be present.

Search control panel for "environment variable" to find the place to set them.

You may also need to check for a setting in the `Adminstrator` user.