# Why i am not able to install Postgresql (PostgreSQL-9.6.2-2-win64-bigsql.exe)? Windows

Tags: postgresql

I am not able to understand why this happen ?

```
Log started 07/02/2018 at 14:08:21
Preferred installation mode : win32
Trying to init installer in mode win32
Mode win32 successfully initialized
[14:08:24] Initializing PostgreSQL installer
[14:08:24] Windows Version is: Windows 7 (6.1)
[14:08:24] Operating System Language is: en
[14:08:24] Current build_identifier is: 9.6.2-2
[14:08:24] System PATH:
**All path of my system** 
[14:08:24] Initializing pg96 variables
[14:08:24] Download url: https://s3.amazonaws.com/pgcentral
[14:08:24] PostgreSQL Locale to install: DEFAULT
Setting variable windows_net_session_exitcode from C:\Users\himanshu-sharma\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_himanshu-sharma/net-session-exit-code.bat 
Script exit code: 1

Script output:


Script stderr:
 '"C:\Users\HIMANS~2\AppData\Local\Temp\POSTGR~1\NET-SE~1.BAT"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Error with configuration or permissions. Please see log file for more information.
```

Comment: I would ask OpenSCG who made the installation package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @RAM answer in this . [Problems Installing PostgreSQL 9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287207/problems-installing-postgresql-9-2)

### Solution:

1. Open command prompt in admin mode
2. Execute following command to change the format based on your drive or all drives

   Sample commands:

   ```
   fsutil 8dot3name set 1    
        This disable 8dot3 name creation on all volumes
   fsutil 8dot3name set C: 1  
        This disable 8dot3 name creation on c:
   ```
3. Execute the installation as a user having admin privileges
4. After install, consider resetting the 8dot3name setting to default (2) to avoid unintended consequences

Hope it solves the problem!